# Create two different icons for a single app

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest

I would like to have a single app with two icons: one is the main icon that launches the main Activity, while the second one is the setup icon, and launches a different Activity.
Unfortunately it seems that android:icon is available only at application level.
How can I configure the manifest to have two different icons and what's the correct way to configure the intent-filters to do it?

Comment: Have two `<activity>` elements, each pointing to a separate `Activity` class and a separate icon, but both having the same `<intent-filter>` for `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER`.

Comment: that's it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution can be using different flavors for your app.

In your app's `build.gradle` file do something like following.

```
android {  
    productFlavors {
      mainActivityFlavor {
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_one"
                launchActivityName="com.example.MainActivity"
        ]

    }

      otherActivityFlavor{
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_two",
                launchActivityName="com.example.OtherActivity"
        ]

    }
  }
}
```

And in your `AndroidManifest` file add this:

```
<activity android:name="${launchActivityName}">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Actually as commonsware said, it's possible to do this without bothering gradle. I knew that but it looks like the android:icon wasn't available among the options and had to be inserted manually, for that reason I thought it was not available at all.